# Angularjs rest call not returning array

Tags: javascript, web-services, angular-services

I have a rest call inside a angularjs app that should be returning an array but does not seem to return anything.

### The angularjs factory is:

```
factory('getManagedObjectList', function($resource){
    return $resource('http://sdo:8081/mars/getManagedObjectList',{},  {
        post: {method:'POST', params: {}, isArray:true}
    })
```

})

### In the angularjs controller I have:

```
$scope.List = getManagedObjectList.post({
isTA5000 : "false",
tId : $scope.matchingTA5000Name},
   function(data){ 
     var items = angular.fromJson(data);                         
     $scope.log = "11User saved//"+items;
   },function(response){
    $scope.log = "11User could not be saved//"+response.status;
});
```

### In the Rest Controller on the java which uses @RestController side I have:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value= "/getManagedList",method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json", consumes="application/json", headers="Accept=application/json")

public String[] getManagedList(@RequestBody EocuBean EocuBean) {

    return service.getManagedList(Eocu.getIsTA5000(),EocuBean.gettId()));
}
```

### The method signature for the method that gets invoked on the java side is:

```
public String[] getManagedList(String isTA5000, String tId)
```

Can anyone help me on this one.

Comment: Eocu.getIsTA5000() is EocuBean.getIsTA5000()

Comment: try getManagedList instead of getManagedObjectList in the request url and also print the error response

Comment: Thats a typo, it is getManagedObjectList in the request url.

Comment: do you see any error in server logs or at your side ?

Comment: the data that is returned is the tId value.

Comment: I added "$scope.getManagedObjectList.$promise.then(function(data){" and I do get a string back if I change "public String[] getManagedList(@RequestBody EocuBean EocuBean)" to "public String getManagedList(@RequestBody EocuBean EocuBean)"

Comment: If I keep it as a String[] I am getting nothing back.